# Connecting quadratic bézier circle in SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

I am creating a random SVG "Blob" generator, but can't figure out how to connect the last bézier to the "M" point correctly. In the example you can see a little spike there.

```js
function generate() {
    const points = [
        { x: 55.380049480163834, y: 8.141661255952418 },
        { x: 61.89338428790346, y: 59.21935310168805 },
        { x: 6.637386502817552, y: 65.10477483405401 },
        { x: 15.309460889587692, y: 11.231848017862793 }
    ]

    let d = `M ${points[0].x / 2} ${points[0].y}`
    d += `Q ${points[0].x} ${points[0].y} ${(points[0].x + points[1].x) * 0.5} ${(points[0].y + points[1].y) * 0.5}`
    d += `Q ${points[1].x} ${points[1].y} ${(points[1].x + points[2].x) * 0.5} ${(points[1].y + points[2].y) * 0.5}`
    d += `Q ${points[2].x} ${points[2].y} ${(points[2].x + points[3].x) * 0.5} ${(points[2].y + points[3].y) * 0.5}`
    d += `Q ${points[3].x} ${points[3].y} ${(points[3].x + points[0].x) * 0.5} ${(points[3].y + points[0].y) * 0.5} Z`

    return d
}

document.getElementById('blob').setAttribute('d', generate())
```

```html
<svg>
<path viewBox="0 0 70 70" id="blob"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your path's starting point is `points[0].x/2 , points[0].y` but your end point is `(points[3].x + points[0].x)/2 , (points[3].y + points[0].y)/2`, and these are not even remotely the same...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That fixes the spike, but makes the "M" point a hard edge.

Comment: It's unclear how exactly your path is supposed to work given the points...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I want to connect the 4 points so they form an uneven circle.

Comment: Well, right now you're using the points themselves as the control point coordinates, not the points to be attached...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it: first you need to find the first midpoint (between the last and the first point ) and move to it. next you calculate the midpoint between every 2 points in the points array. Finally you draw the curve through the last point, back to the first midpoint.

```js
const points = [
        { x: 55.380049480163834, y: 8.141661255952418 },
        { x: 61.89338428790346, y: 59.21935310168805 },
        { x: 6.637386502817552, y: 65.10477483405401 },
        { x: 15.309460889587692, y: 11.231848017862793 }
    ]



function drawCurve(points) {
  //find the first midpoint and move to it
  var p = {};
  p.x = (points[points.length - 1].x + points[0].x) / 2;
  p.y = (points[points.length - 1].y + points[0].y) / 2;
  
  let d = `M${p.x}, ${p.y}`;
  //curve through the rest, stopping at each midpoint
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
    var mp = {}
    mp.x = (points[i].x + points[i + 1].x) / 2;
    mp.y = (points[i].y + points[i + 1].y) / 2;
    d += `Q${points[i].x},${points[i].y},${mp.x},${mp.y}`

  }
  //curve through the last point, back to the first midpoint
  d+= `Q${points[points.length - 1].x},${points[points.length - 1].y},${p.x},${p.y}`
  blob.setAttributeNS(null,"d",d)
}


drawCurve(points);
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid; fill:none; stroke:black; width:300px;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 70 70" >
<path id="blob"></path>
</svg>
```